# How I can do join in ClickHouse with IpV4 and Ipv4 Range

Tags: sql, join, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I trying do join with ipv4 in table1 and range ipv4 table2:

table1:
user_id(int), ipv4(type ipv4)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 122222 | 1.0.0.1 |
| 323232 | 1.0.0.2 |

table2:
range_start(type ipv4), range_end(type ipv4), country(string)

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0.0.1 | 1.0.0.256 | US |
| 1.0.0.1 | 2.0.0.256 | JP |

I don't have idea how I can do this without using code python for example. I need do this via only sql. Maybe you have ideas?

I try imagine if I have CIDR in table2 and try this join:

table1 left join table2 on isIPAddressInRange(ipv4, CIDR), but it bot working in ClickHouse